# Any advice on choosing a Netlify CMS template?

Tags: content-management-system, blogs, netlify-cms, jamstack

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhHio.png)I was originally working toward setting up a Wordpress blog for a friend...
The requirements are that:

-they would not need to do any 'code related' or tricky admin tasks pertaining to maintaining the site.

-they would have a unique domain.

-they can sign in from anywhere and write content.

-SEO is important.

The simple UI contributor interface of WP was very appealing. Though with some research I have decided to choose a JAMstack orientated blog. And going with Netlify CMS instead of a headless WP.

There are some templates available from Netlify. I was hoping to get some advice on which template to choose. They are all fairly new to me.

But ease of use, SEO, and various pretty designs would be my main desires.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to JAMStack development, I suggest use [Stackbit](https://app.stackbit.com/dashboard). They develop some awesome templates and take care of netlifyCMS setup, which can be quite some chores.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Templates available [here](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/start-with-a-template/), then they are less to do with Netlify-CMS, and just what Jamstack tool you want to use.

The CMS itself looks the same for all of the templates, all they do is give you an example of how you can wire up NetlifyCMS to various popular site-generation tools.

My personal opinion would be either Next.JS or Eleventy, as they are relatively easy to use with good SEO out of the box, but your personal previous experience and preferences on which JamStack tool to use for this blog would be the defining factor.